# GROUP BY syntax is causing "missing expression" error

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, group-by

Please explain why the following query:

```
select      in.status                    as "no_installments"
,           count(in.id)             as "installment"
FROM        instalsched.instalment in
GROUP       BY in.status;
```

returns

> ORA-00936: missing expression
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 1 Column: 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in` is a key word in SQL.  It is used as part of a where clause, such as `where person_id in (1,2,3,4)`.  To remedy, simply change the alias.

```
select
   in1.status as "no_installments",           
   count(in1.id)             as "installment"
FROM instalsched.instalment in1
GROUP BY in1.status;
```

Answer (score 0):

`in` is a keyword. Use a different alias or wrap it in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

"in" is a reserved word in SQL syntax. You should try to use other non-reserved word like "inst" or something similar.